# How many isosceles triangles do you need to make any polygon?

Tags: geometry

A while back, I had a question regarding constructing shapes with only isosceles triangles. I decided to give it a go again and it has once again stumped me. The question is:

How many isosceles triangles would you need to be able to construct any $n$ sided polygon?

I thought induction could work, but dealing with non convex polygons may make this difficult. I tried by finding polygons that require what I thought was the maximum amount, but this is unreliable and may not be enough to find a general expression in terms of $n$.

How would one go about solving a problem like this? Is this a well known result? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try it with quadrilaterals first? First, simple ones, then the difficult scalene-types.

Comment: I considered cyclic, non cyclic, convex and non convex, but I couldn't really get anywhere with it.

Comment: What about a $3-4-5$ right triangle?

Comment: A 3-4-5 triangle (or any right triangle) would be constructed with 2 isosceles triangles. But some triangles cannot be constructed with only 2 isosceles so the minimum needed to construct all triangles would be greater. @Somos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [two ears theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_ears_theorem) which states for $n > 3$, any simple $n$-gon has at least two  ears.

If one split a $n$-gon at an [ear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28geometry%29#Ears), we get a triangle and a $(n-1)$-gon.

For any triangle $ABC$ with $BC$ being the longest side.

- If $ABC$ is a right triangle, the circumcenter $O$ coincides with midpoint of $BC$, we can decompose $ABC$ into two isosceles triangle $ABO$, $AOC$.
- Otherwise, let $D$ be the foot on $BC$. We can split $ABC$ first into two 
  right triangles $ABD$, $ADC$ and then into $4$ isosceles triangles.

In general, we can decompose any triangle into at most $4$ isosceles triangles.

By induction on $n$, we find we can split a $n$-gon into at most $4n$ isosceles triangles. This bound is probably not optimal but at least we know the decomposition is always possible.

**Update**

For general triangle, the bound $4$ is optimal.

If triangle $ABC$ is acute, we can decompose it into $3$ isosceles triangles: $AOB$, $BOC$ and $COA$. If $ABC$ is a right triangle, $2$ is enough. This leaves us with the case of obtuse scalene triangles.

A literature search indicate in $2004$, Kosztolányi, et al${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$ has studied the problem of decomposing obtuse scalene triangles into $3$ isosceles triangles.

With help of a computer, they found there are $23$ families of solutions. 
Let $\alpha > 90^\circ > \beta > \gamma$ be the angles of the trangle.
In all these solutions, $\alpha, \beta$ are rational linear combinations of $180^\circ$ and $\gamma$.
In particular, this implies triangle with angles
$$(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \left( (5-\sqrt{2})\cdot 30^\circ, 30\sqrt{2}^\circ, 30^\circ \right)$$
cannot be decomposed into $3$ isosceles triangles. It is not hard to verify we cannot decompose this triangle into $2$ isosceles triangles. This means for general triangle, the bound $4$ is optimal.

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - Kosztolányi, József & Kovács, Zoltán & Nagy, Erzsébet. (2004). *Decomposition of triangles into isosceles triangles II. Complete solution of the problem by using a computer*. Teaching Mathematics and Computer Science. 2. 275-300. 10.5485/TMCS.2004.0059.

  An online copy can be found [here](http://tmcs.math.unideb.hu/load_doc.php?p=42&t=doc).

Comment: This way makes sense, but I'm looking for the proven ideal case. Is there any way to prove that this could be the ideal case? If not, how would I be able to find the ideal case (and prove it)?

Comment: @Schnappi I have no idea what is the optimal one. As you can see, by the time you make the comment, I already improve the bound from $6n$ to $4n$. This sort of problem tend to be hard. The best course of action is doing a literature search.

Answer (score 0):

If I combine the isosceles triangle side by side, I'll create a different polygon, but at some certain combination, it will still produce same shape

Just like when I join two parallelogram side by side, it also creates a parallelogram which is still a quadrilateral

so I'll assume your question about the minimum number of isosceles triangle needed to make a polygon of $n$ sides

$1$ ∆ is a $3$ sided polygon

$2$ ∆ makes a quadrilateral

$3$ ∆ makes a 5 sides polygon

so at least $n$ number of isosceles triangle makes a $(n+2)$ sided polygon

Comment: The question is more working the other way around. The question wants it for all possible polygons with n sides, if it were broken down into isosceles triangles, what would be the most ideal way to do this to minimise the amount of triangles? In other words, if you were trying to break up the shape in as least amount of isosceles triangles as possible, what would be the most triangles you require to make up an n sided polygon?